# How to run deluge from CLI?

Tags: command-line, deluge

I want to run deluge in tty3,4,5 . but when I type it there is, No display warning. Then I give top and there is no pid on deluge that is deluge is not running. How do I run it from CLI so that it keeps downloading the torrents?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Have you started `deluged` (the `deluge` daemon) as a service? The command for running the client in CLI is `deluge-console`.

Here are some guides:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Deluge
- https://whatbox.ca/wiki/Deluge_Console_Documentation

Comment: thanx... deluge-console did help/

Comment: Don't install `deluge`!!! just `apt install deluged deluge-console`

Answer (score 8):

This will install it, set up the daemon, and connect to its console:

`sudo apt-get install deluge deluged deluge-console`

`deluged`

`deluge-console`

You can then add torrents like:

`add -p /user/Downloads torrent_magnet_link`

Comment: everything is great, except you don't need to install deluge, just deluged and deluge-console

Answer (score 0):

You could also try the local web UI.

Install deluge-web using your package manager (if not already installed). On Ubuntu, you can use

`sudo apt-get install deluge-web`.

Start the deluge-web service. You can do this by typing `deluge-web` in your terminal.

Once it's running, open a web browser and navigate to http://localhost:8112. This is the default address for the Deluge web interface.

The **default password is deluge**. Upon first login, you'll be prompted to change this password.

Once logged in, you can add, manage, and remove torrents just like you would in the desktop client.